# Convert png image to blob image with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, base64, tinymce

I am unable to display my image tag generated by a canvas tag which contains "png" binary data. I want to be able to display this new image in TinyMCE editor so I can edit it with the FMath plugin.

[image: fmath plugin in tinymce editor]

When I hover over the img tag which is empty, I get error "Failed to load the given URL".

The image at the bottom is my canvas tag containing the png data. I should somehow transfer that png data to img tag with blob address so that I can edit it with FMath editor:

[image: fmath plugin in tinymce 2]

The code I am using is this:

```
var tinymceapp = (function (jq, tmce) {'use strict';
    var canvas = null,
        ctx = null,
        base64String = "",
        img = null,
        blob = null;

    return {
        pageReady: function () {
            tmce.init({
                selector: '#editor',
                height: 500,
                theme: 'modern',
                plugins: [
                    'other plugins FMathEditor'
                ],
                toolbar1: 'toolbar 1 buttons',
                toolbar2: 'toolbar 2 buttons | FMathEditor',

                init_instance_callback : function(editor) {
                    img = new Image();
                    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                    img.onload = function () {
                       canvas.width = this.width;
                       canvas.height = this.height;
                       ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                    };

                    img.src = 'img/math.png';

                    base64String = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1.0);

                    blob = canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
                        var newImg = document.createElement('img'),
                        url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        console.log(url);
                        newImg.onload = function() {
                            // no longer need to read the blob so it's revoked
                            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                        };

                        newImg.src = url;
                        document.body.appendChild(newImg);
                    }, 'image/png', 1.0);

                    tmce.activeEditor.insertContent('<img alt="MathML (base64):' + base64String.substring(22, base64String.length) + '" src="' + base64String + '"/>');

                }
            });
        }
    };
}($, tinymce));

$(document).ready(tinymceapp.pageReady);
```

I tried both approaches with Canvas.toDataUrl() and with Canvas.toBlob(). But both generate blank image.

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

The below image show the generate img tag with the toBlob() code:

[image: fmath plugin in tinymce editor, toBlob]

This is an example img tag which cannot be displayed:

```
<img src="blob:http://localhost:8081/9fd2d43d-3b7f-42cd-a50d-161263d70c55" alt="MathML (base64):iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAACWCAYAAABkW7XSAAAAxUlEQVR4nO3BMQEAAADCoPVPbQhfoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOA1v9QAATX68/0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" data-mce-selected="1">
```

This is the bottom blank img tag, generated by canvas.toBlob():

```
<img src="blob:http://localhost:8081/eede9470-3728-4031-8c58-9c29a4c8979f">
```

Comment: any working url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get blob while image loading has not yet completed.
Basically you need to wait for image loaded before you can proceed with capturing the blob (async).

So here in this step:

```
img.onload = function () {
   canvas.width = this.width;
   canvas.height = this.height;
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
   // YOU SHOULD PROCESS / CALLBACK IT HERE
};
// HERE IS WHERE YOU DO IT AS OF NOW
```